# Importing module from a different package in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, dependencies

This is a conceptual question.

I'm an absolute beginner on both Angular and npm, so this is surely a basic question, but I have been looking all over and haven't found an answer.

I want to do a little proof of concept before starting a project. **I want to have a package called Imported and reuse it in a package called Importer**

Importer's package.json has Imported as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "imported": "file:../Imported",
    ...
}
```

Imported is in Importer's node_modules folder, as expected.

I've followed [Angular's documentation on reusing modules](https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules). The example they describe is exactly what I want, only that I want to do it from inside a dependency.

So I've imported ImportedAppModule in Importer's app.module.ts.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ImportedAppModule } from 'imported/src/app/app.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    ImportedAppModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've also exported the component in Imported's app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { ImportedAppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ImportedAppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ImportedAppComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ImportedAppComponent]
})
export class ImportedAppModule { }
```

With this setup, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR in ../imported/src/app/app.module.ts Module build failed: Error:
>   \imported\src\app\app.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript
>   compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files'
>   or 'include' property.

So it seemed that I had to include this dependency in tsconfig.app.json. But I also read somewhere that I didn't have to include it there, and that I had to include it in the Importer's bootstrap array.
I tried both, none of them worked, but that's fine, the configuration details are out of the scope of this question.

My question is, which one is it? **What's the normal way to do this? Am I on the right track here? If so, what's the next step?**

I have tried using ng build --aot in the Imported package, and added the dependency to the dist folder in Importer, but it fails and says it doesn't have a package.json, so I thought I might just try to do it jit. Still, I want to know how to do this with aot.

I would really appreciate some guidance. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `ng-packagr` that Transpile your libraries to Angular Package Format
execute `npm install ng-packagr --save-dev`

Refer this [Building an Angular 4 Component Library with the Angular CLI and ng-packagr](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e).

Comment: Thank you so much. I followed it and it worked exactly like I wanted.