# Reuse shared Angular module among apps - free and private?

Tags: angular

I am at the point where I have created several angular projects.  I copy/paste code from one project to the next.  Time to move on and create modules that can be reused.  I am stuck with a blocker.  There does not seem to be a clear solution for how to go about doing this without giving away the store.

A guy named Yakov Fain has a blog for setting up multiple apps in a single project.  Works like a charm!   Free firebase hosting and functions turn out to be a nightmare or impossible with his setup.

The maintstream way to do this is to use npm to publish modules.  I do not want to release my code for all to see.

One year ago someone had a stackoverflow article about how to use npm with GitHub.   Under this setup either you pay npm $7/month or you pay GitHub $7/month to keep the code private.

There was a post or two regarding how to use npm with BitBucket to do this job.  Bitbucket lets you have a few private projects for free.  It was sparse and not very helpful.

I cannot believe I am the only person who wants to reuse subsystems among projects, does not want to pay $7/month, and does not want to let everyone see my code.   Any suggestions for how to go about doing this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49055450/5695162)

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally tried this myself, but you can create your own personal private npm registry that you wouldn't have to pay a fee for: http://clock.co.uk/blog/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository

For myself, I'm using npm to host modules for a open source project, and it works very well, but in my case I don't mind sharing the code publicly.