# How to package local NPM packages

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

Hi I have downloaded an already exists npm module from github and made some changes in it, Now I want to install it as npm install locally , but while i have used npm install for that folder. It is successfully installed without being compiled i.e i am seeing ts file instead of js file. I have used following options.

```
1) npm init
2) npm pack
```

as suggested by many blogs , so please suggest me how to achieve my requirement of using that package as local package.

Comment: what is the package that you are using?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/49055450/5695162

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you seem to have two issues.
1. ts files not compiled to js.
2. how to use your local package.

For compiling the ts files to js, you need to run tsc. Check this quick [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) tutorial.

Once you compiled your ts files to js output, there are two ways you can use that as your local package.

**1. [npm pack](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack)**
When you run npm pack, a new zip file will be created and you just "npm install xyz.zip".

**2. [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)**
This is basically creating a symlink for the package you are trying to install.

Comment: "*1. npm pack When you run npm pack, a new zip file will be created and you just "npm install xyz.zip". If this*" <<< Was there more to come here after "If this"? ;^)

Comment: @ruffin My answer was several months old and I don't remember what I was trying to add after "If this".